# Is this a realistic set of world maps?

Tags: internal-consistency, geography

I want to start by thanking everybody in this community as your posts have been instrumental in helping me to build my world. All I am asking for is a final review of the maps that I have created thus far and any details that should be changed to make the maps more realistic. Thank you in advance.

Some things to note:

1. Everything except for the polar ice caps is included in the maps.
2. This world has roughly the same surface area as Earth.
3. This world has a slightly higher water content than Earth, which I hope is enough to account for the increased prevalence of forests.
4. The world is flat but the problems associated with this are remedied through the power of the gods ie. the god of sun pulls the sun across the sky and moves its path north and south to create the seasons, the gods of wind do their part to maintain earth like weather patterns, and the god of the sea is responsible for currents.
   [image: Biome Map]

[image: General Moisture Map]

[image: Plate-Tectonics Map]

[image: Currents Map]

[image: Wind Map]

Comment: In the third map by "fault lines" I assume you mean spreading centers. correct.

Comment: Also note swamps are rarely massive things, since they are caused by local elevation, a huge swamp butted right up to a desert is very unlikely. ON a map of that scale swamps would be hard to see.

Comment: If it is flat, what do the edges represent?  Edge, wall, infinite expanse? And by realistic, it seems you are saying that the world is flat, but the mechanics for natural effects should be considered to be as if the world is a sphere because the gods handle any discrepancy?

Comment: Seems weird to have a flat world that mimics the wind and current patterns of a non-flat world, and has the same shape and aspect of a conventionally projected non-flat world. Seems like you should have made more of that.

Comment: John, yes spreading centers would be a better term thank you. As for the swamp, I suppose I used very similar colors to differentiate between swamps and tropical savanna. The only swamp area is in the bottom left corner. Michael, the edges represent a magical firmament, and yes it otherwise behaves like a spherical world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks fairly good. Took me a second to realise why your ocean currents were running along the map edges and not crossing to the other side.

[image: your map]

Areas marked 1 and 2  Depending how your oceans connect in the West and East, there are some issues.
If they act like typical spherical planet oceans *through* the magical firmanent, then they need to cross the map boundaries.
If they hit the magical firmanent boundary, then there are some ripple effects. The sea god could create forces to negate this rebound affect.

The north and south areas will need some way to connect. 
Warm water pushing outwards on the surface and colder water encroaching towards the equator in the deeper currents. This will allow for proper interconnected ocean dynamics and some related weather effects. Check out [Teleconnection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleconnection).

I also believe your eastern mountainous islands will be alot greener and wetter than frozen tundra/taiga. I know it's a cold current to the west of the islands and its in the high latitudes but the moisture from the oceans could negate alot of the dry cold weather effects, along a thin strip of land. (Especially if there is warm water spreading upwards along your Eastern map boundary). At a push it could be similar to [Argentina climate zones](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Argentina), but your islands look a lot narrower and remind me more of [New Zealand](https://www.sciencelearn.org.nz/images/774-new-zealand-surface-currents), which is surrounded by a warmer current so it doesn't quite match.

Area marked 3. This will be a large warmish collection of seas. The cold dry wind blowing south from your mountains will hit the warm wet air over the water and create large thunderstorms/snowstorms. It should also create a greener  wetter climate area downwind, not the dry desert sliver you have to the southwest of the northern mountain range.

Comment: If someone can please fix my image/webpage links. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the green tick. Just a quick friendly tip. It's recommended to wait awhile (~24 hours) before giving the tick so that you don't have to keep switching accepted answers, and to give users in different timezones time to have a look at the question and think of an answer. I did the same thing at first 

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I hadn't even considered that.

Comment: @DavidCoffron, thanks for the edit. My brain was too fried to work out my error...it was 9am...

Answer (score 4):

The maps look good! Two main things I would change though. The size of the swamps, and the different biomes on either side of most mountains. Usually, (for tall peaked mountains) the moisture levels on one side would be vastly different from the moisture levels on the other side. Which you did sometimes, but not always.

Answer (score 4):

Nice work. Only comment I have is regarding your tectonic map.

### Plates

On a world with similar tectonic activity that we see on Earth, the edges of tectonic plates often break apart or merge leading to smaller plates in addition to the larger ones. I would recommend adding some of these smaller plates at the collision points of continental plates containing proximal continental masses.

[image]

### Mountains

Using the same map, consider moving your mountain distribution to be centered on these collision points. The vast majority of large mountain ranges appear on these plate boundaries where as yours, on the contrary, seem fairly evenly distributed.

Answer (score 3):

Nice work

The last illustration of Coriolis effect need to be tweaked because it only works on round world.

Unless you flip one of them and make the arrows combine in the equator to form a giant constant cyclone

Good luck

Comment: Agreed, this is what I was going to add! Specifically, deflections only occur on a *rotating* spherical world in order to preserve angular momentum